# Java Array and sub-array

Tags: java, arrays

In the picture I created an array that I gave 15 as an argument. I have inserted random integers between 0 and 5 (inclusive) into this directory.

1) number of plains,
2) the widest width of the flat and
3) this widest plane is the starting point in the array

How can I write a screen-displaying program in Java programming language?

(For example, the array is 1 0 5 5 5 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 0 1. The number of levels is 8. That is, by taking the same number of repetitions of 1, the array becomes a sub-array which is the same as all components. The largest plain 4 4 4 4 is the largest level number 4. The largest level is the first 4, 9th elements in the array.)

Please help me.

Code:

```
public class Zehra {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);  
        int[] x = new int[N];  

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)  
            x[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6);  
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)  
            System.out.print(x[i] + " ");  

        System.out.println(" ");  
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the code in your question.

Comment: For me, it is not clear what you want to do. Please be more precise about what you want to do.

Comment: *The number of levels is 8.* - I don't know what that means. What is a plain? All you seem to ask is find the largest section of repetitions, but have no code to attempt that

Comment: Very unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unclear to me too.

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: The example is great for the understanding. Only one question: when the answer to the widest width of the flat is 4, is that because there are 4 equal numbers in a row, oris it because it’s the number 4 being repeated? In other words, if the array contained the sequence 3 3 3 3 3, would the answer be 3 or 5?

Answer (score 2):

Don’t expect anyone around here to write the code for you. Rather I’d try to guide you in the right direction. Iterate once through the array, all the time keeping track of:

- The start index of the current run of equal elements
- The value of the current run
- The number of runs encountered
- The start index and length of the longest run of equal elements before the current.

Whenever you encounter a number that is *not* equal to the value in the current run, you know that a new run begins. At this time (a) add one to the count of runs (b) see if the run that is ending is longer than the previous longest run, and if so, record it as the new longest run, both its start index and its length. After the loop ends, remember to count the last run and see if it is longer than any other run.